# How do I specifiy a path to a file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, io

Ok this is a homework questions, but I cannot find the answer anywhere, not even in the book.

Path to Files
If the user wants to specify a path for a file, the typical forward slash is replaced by __________________.

can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double back-slashes. (\\)

However, the more portable solution is to use File.separator, as described [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: Java should automatically convert forward-slashes in file paths to back-slashes if the OS (Windows) so requires, so I don't think that the question is about that.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, "/" works on all platforms.

Comment: What is "all platforms"? Java runs on a LOT more than Windows, Linux and OS X. You have NO guarantee that / works on other platforms that your code might one day run on.

Comment: For the sake of argument, the question is from a file system stand point, that too on Windows. I just meant popular OSs when I said "all platforms" - Unfortunately your java skills in one device platform(say, server/desktop) does not hold good for other devices (mobile/embedded)

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.separator`.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the platform - on windows, it'll be replaced by 'c:\', on Unix it'll be left as '/'